# repeat command substituting value from text file

Tags: bash

I'd like to run an ldapsearch query repeatedly substituting the uid from a list and output results to a new file.

```
ldapsearch -h ldap.com -p 389 -x -b "dc=top,dc=com" \
              "uid=**value_from_a_text_file**" >>ldap.query.results.
```

Are there any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is a list of UIDs, one-per-line, and is named uidfile.txt

```
for line in `cat uidfile.txt`; do
    ldapsearch -h ldap.com -p 389 -x -b "dc=top,dc=com" "uid=${line}" >>ldap.query.results
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming data in CSV format with first field as UID

```
awk -F ","  '{print $1}' data.csv | \
while read uiddata
do 
 ldapsearch -h ldap.com -p 389 -x -b "dc=top,dc=com" "uid=${uiddata}" >> ldap.query.results

done
```